# Filtering Results without Refetching Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a web page that allows users to display a filtered set of results from an external service.  The service is slow and the data is returned in xml chunks, which I then have to parse.  I very much want to avoid fetching and parsing this data more than once, but I can't figure out how to apply the filter string to the data after I fetch it.

Below are the pieces I have so far (simplified significantly).

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
  List<ComplexObject> objList = FetchAndParseNastyXMLData();
  HandyViewModel vm = new HandyViewModel(objList);
  return View(vm);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class HandyViewModel(List<ComplexObject> objList) {
  public List<ComplexObject> AllObjects { get; private set; }
  public List<ComplexObject> FilteredObjects { get; private set; }
  ... //other handy properties

  public HandyViewModel(List<ComplexObject> objList) {
    AllObjects = objList;
    FilteredObjects = null;
  }

  public void ApplyFilter(string filter) {
    FilteredObjects = AllObjects.Where(r => r.filter_field == filter).ToList();
  }
}
```

View:

```
@model ViewModels.HandyViewModel

<div>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("FilterList", "Controller")) {
    <fieldset id="Filters">
      <legend>Filter List</legend>
      <input type="text" name="FilterString" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
  }
</div>
<div>
  @foreach(ComplexObject o in Model.FilteredList) {
    <p>o.ToString()</p>
  }
</div>
```

I'm stuck at the point of trying to handle the form submission.  I think I want to add another function to the controller, but I can't figure out how to continue operating on the existing list of objects.  Can I pass that list back to the Controller somehow so that I can re-use it?  This is what I'm trying to do, but perhaps there is some better way...

```
public ActionResult FilterList(string FilterString) {
  //how do I get my List<ComplexObject> here without re-fetching and re-parsing the data?!
  HandyViewModel vm = new HandyViewModel(objList);
  vm.ApplyFilter(FilterString);
  return View(vm);
}
```

I've dug up tons of examples for filter/results pages online, but they all seem to re-fetch the data when applying the filter.

Comment: Yes you need to re-fetch the data. The only property you post back is the `FilterString`. If you concerned about the performance of the external service and parsing the data, consider fetching and parsing it once and caching the data (MemoryCache, Session etc). Some of your view model properties seem unnecessary. Why not just one List<ComplexObject> which is set in the controller?

Comment: And if you are initially displaying all items, you could just use jquery to hide/show the items based on the filter text and avoid having to post back and re-fetch a filtered list.